# How to disable Ok button if user select the previous date and time?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to disable the OK button in dialog fragment if user want to select the previous date and time from current time.
This is the library https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker
that I am using in my project by setting up minimum date I am able to prevent user to select previous date but didn't find a way for time .

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.jjobes.slidedatetimepicker.SlideDateTimeListener;
import com.github.jjobes.slidedatetimepicker.SlideDateTimePicker;

/**
 * Sample test class for SlideDateTimePicker.
 *
 * @author jjobes
 *
 */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private SimpleDateFormat mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa");
    private Button mButton;

    private SlideDateTimeListener listener = new SlideDateTimeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateTimeSet(Date date)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    mFormatter.format(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Optional cancel listener
        @Override
        public void onDateTimeCancel()
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                new SlideDateTimePicker.Builder(getSupportFragmentManager())
                        .setListener(listener)
                        .setInitialDate(new Date())
                        .setMinDate(new Date())
                        //.setMaxDate(maxDate)
                        .setIs24HourTime(false)
                        //.setTheme(SlideDateTimePicker.HOLO_DARK)
                        //.setIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"))
                        .build()
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this or suggest me if not so suggest me some link by which I put date and time picker on single dialog box . I checkout most solution but no one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to edit the library

1)Add the Library manually by adding as a package not using gradle

2)Go to this class `SlideDateTimeDialogFragment.java`

3) Find the declaration of onDateChanged and onTimeChanged

4) Now Add your validation in these methods

```
 @Override
    public void onDateChanged(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        mCalendar.set(year, month, day);
        updateDateTab();
    if(Your validations==true){
    mOkButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else{
    mOkButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    }
```

And

```
 @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(int hour, int minute)
    {
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        updateTimeTab();
  if(Your validations==true){
        mOkButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else{
        mOkButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What to set for your validation ? sir

Comment: use current date object for date and time validations

Comment: or use a current date calendar object and validate the time and date

Comment: Did not work brother is just use the condition if(mCalendar.before(mMinDate)==true) but it doesn't work for me

Comment: what is mcalendar and mMindate ?

Comment: Have you run it on by yourself I think if you run it after that you will understand and able to give a accepted answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132488/discussion-between-champandorid-and-quick-learner).

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help to compare current date and selected date:

```
@Override
public void onDateTimeSet(Date date) {

    if (date.before(new Date())) {
        // past date
    }else{
        // future or current date
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            mFormatter.format(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anjali but I am able to prevent user to select previous date I want is there any option to prevent from previous time also ?

Comment: thats not what he asked for @anjali

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I looked for this library, found it and compiled it to my project, and I saw that you have to take the project inside to yours and then add the following line to gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
}
```

Because of that, go to this library project files, edit the following file SlideDateTimeDialogFragment, inside it you will find the mOKButton code, edit it like the following:

[image]

NOTE: Don't forget to sync with gradle again afterwards.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point I did all things successfully . All of that i want to prevent user to select past time.

Comment: So check if the current time (Time at "new Date()") is later than the selected time. other wise the mOkButton,Onclick event will just the "Return" - meaning - clicking OK button wont do anything unless the time selected is in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);




                        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                                        {
                                                dates = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                                                txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                                        }
                                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

                        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: This worked for me when I was tryin to get the same thing done.

Comment: setMinDate() does the job  for you

Answer (score 0):

Simply use date picker which can't select previous date like this:

```
 int mYear,mMonth,mDay;
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.datepicker,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        insertdate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: This method won't select previous date so user can't Input date back then current.